How to perform transaction using Solana Phantom on client-side (browser)?
As the title says, I am trying to perform a transaction through the browser. I got the connection to work, and added the script tag:
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@solana/web3.js@latest/lib/index.iife.js"></script>

However, I can't seem to connect to SolanaWeb3 to perform the transaction, and I could not find resources that use only the browser. Is it not possible?
Here is the current code (currently getting a Buffer error)
 const provider = window.phantom?.solana // see "Detecting the Provider"
      try {
        const resp = await provider.connect()
        console.log(resp.publicKey.toString())
        // 26qv4GCcx98RihuK3c4T6ozB3J7L6VwCuFVc7Ta2A3Uo
        // make a transaction using phantom
        const connection = new solanaWeb3.Connection(
          solanaWeb3.clusterApiUrl('devnet')
        )
        try {
          const transaction = new solanaWeb3.Transaction().add(
            solanaWeb3.SystemProgram.transfer({
              fromPubkey: resp.publicKey,
              toPubkey: new solanaWeb3.PublicKey(
                'someaddress'
              ),
              lamports: 10000,
            })
          )
          // Set recent blockhash
          transaction.recentBlockhash = (
            await connection.getRecentBlockhash()
          ).blockhash

          // Set fee payer
          transaction.feePayer = provider.publicKey
          // Request user to sign and send the transaction via Phantom
          let signedTransaction = await provider.signTransaction(transaction)
          let signature = await connection.sendRawTransaction(
            signedTransaction.serialize()
          )

          // Optionally, await confirmation
          await connection.confirmTransaction(signature)
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err)
        }
      } catch (err) {
        // { code: 4001, message: 'User rejected the request.' }
      }


The Buffer error is because Buffer is a Node.JS class and all examples around are based on react mostly, and they forget to mention that. Even when using modern package managers one gets that error very often unless you configure Node Polyfills
https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyterlab-extension-node-polyfill-and-buffer-error/15169
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-node-polyfills
I think the SDK should be updated to use Textencoder() instead of Buffer(), but it is not yet available.

The best way to connect to solana wallets in the browser is to use the solana wallet adapter.
https://github.com/anza-xyz/wallet-adapter
You can then send transactions like this for examples:
  const { publicKey, sendTransaction } = useWallet()

      const transaction = await program.methods
        .chopTree(GAME_DATA_SEED, transactionCounter)
        .accounts({
          player: playerDataPDA,
          gameData: gameDataPDA,
          signer: publicKey,
          sessionToken: null,
        })
        .transaction()

      const txSig = await sendTransaction(transaction, connection, {
        skipPreflight: true,
      })

You can use the preset
npx create-solana-dapp name

to create a full project using the wallet adapter and nextjs.
In case you dont want to use the wallet adapter most wallets inject their wallet under window.walletName so for example window.phantom for phantom wallet. You can read the docs for that here:
https://docs.phantom.app/solana/detecting-the-provider
https://docs.phantom.app/phantom-deeplinks/provider-methods/signtransaction
Using phantom with vanilla js this would look smth like this:
const transaction = new Transaction();
const { signature } = await 
provider.signAndSendTransaction(transaction);

See the phantom docs here for more details:
Detecting the provider:
https://docs.phantom.app/solana/detecting-the-provider
and sending the transaction:
https://docs.phantom.app/solana/sending-a-transaction

I was looking for an option that does not use React/Next, just vanila JS. I did use the window.phantom method for the connection, but I can't figure out the transaction set up on vanilla js

ah i see. I updated the answer

Hey Jonas, you still did not answer my question. The wallet adapter does not document its utility in vanilla JS. I have updated my question to have my full code (which does not work).

Whats the error you are getting?
